# How to convert velocity piece of code to freemarker code

Tags: java, velocity, freemarker

```
    public static String evaluateByVelocity(final String template, final Map<String, ?>... placeHolders) throws Exception {

    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try {
        Velocity.init();

        final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        // context.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
        if (placeHolders != null) {
            for (final Map plh : placeHolders) {
                copyIntoContext(context, plh);
            }
        }

        Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "LOG", template);
        return writer.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(ex);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this method for freemarker

```
public static String evaluateByFreemarker(final String template, final Map<String, ?>... placeHolders) throws Exception {

    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try {

        // Instantiate an engine through Configuration Class
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER);

        if (placeHolders != null) {
            for (final Map plh : placeHolders) {
                plh.put(placeHolders, plh);
            }
        }

        return writer.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(ex);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I am struck at this part of code

```
Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "LOG", template);
```

Is there any built-in method in freemarker to replace above code

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke freemarker?

Comment: I want to convert this velocity code to freemarker.

Comment: Try the official documentation: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart.html, or even http://www.vogella.com/articles/FreeMarker/article.html